Issue with Camera Plugin in Flutter: Multiple "Package does not exist" Errors in Android Studio
I'm having issues building my Flutter project with Java 17 and the latest version of Android Studio with Android SDK 34. This is my first build attempt, and I've also tried other Java versions, but the problem persists. The project fails to compile with numerous errors related to missing Android packages.
Setup

Java Version: 17 (also tried other versions)
Android Studio Version: Latest (Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1)
Gradle Version: 8.6

Error Log:
I'm getting a large number of errors indicating that various Android packages do not exist. Below are some examples of the errors I'm seeing:
/Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.10.9+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPropertiesImpl.java:7: error: package android.graphics does not exist
import android.graphics.Rect;
                       ^
/Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.10.9+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPropertiesImpl.java:8: error: package android.hardware.camera2 does not exist
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
                               ^
...
/Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.10.9+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/DartMessenger.java:7: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Handler;
                 ^
/Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.10.9+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/DartMessenger.java:8: error: package android.text does not exist
import android.text.TextUtils;
                   ^

Steps Taken:

Installed Java 17 (also tried other versions).
Updated Android Studio to the latest version.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Checked and updated all dependencies in pubspec.yaml.

Questions:

What could be causing these "package does not exist" errors?
Are there any specific configurations required for Java 17 in Flutter projects?
How can I resolve these errors to successfully build my project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
